# error while installing pandas on ubuntu 14

Tags: python, pandas, installation

I am trying to install pandas on my ubuntu machine.

I am using this command

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

I am getting the following error

```
 Downloading pandas-0.25.1.tar.gz (12.6MB): 12.6MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py) egg_info for package pandas
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py", line 21, in <module>
        import versioneer
      File "versioneer.py", line 1629
        print("Adding sample versioneer config to setup.cfg", file=sys.stderr)
                                                                  ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/tmp/pip_build_root/pandas/setup.py", line 21, in <module>

    import versioneer

  File "versioneer.py", line 1629

    print("Adding sample versioneer config to setup.cfg", file=sys.stderr)

                                                              ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can any one please help me with this .

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Adding sample versioneer config to setup.cfg", file=sys.stderr)
```

It is a `Python 3` syntax.

- First install `Python 3`.
- Then run `sudo pip3 install pandas` or `python3 -m pip install pandas`.

Comment: I have python 3 installed in my machine . It is 3.7.0

Comment: Then use sudo pip3 install pandas

Comment: try sudo pip install pandas==0.24.2

Comment: try python3 -m pip install pandas

Comment: It is giving me RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: for python3 -m pip install pandas  this command here It is just saying collecting pandas and nothing is happening.

Comment: Python is 3.7 as I have checked using python --version

Comment: Yes it is 3.7.0

Comment: Sorry I mean check if pandas is installed or not.

Comment: pandas is not installed. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: You are running it using python3 file.py or python file.py?

Comment: Actually  it is saying virtualenv --python=python3.7 .env

Comment: Use python3 file.py to run the file and check if you can import pandas or not.

Comment: Actually I am totally new , so I am not getting what you are saying. Sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200507/discussion-between-dipen-dadhaniya-and-ganesh-kaspate).